# "Texted" as past tense of "text"

Tags: past-tense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use “Text” as verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/how-to-use-text-as-verb)

If I sent someone a text on my mobile phone would I say I *texted* them? 
We say *I'll text you* so now it's out there as a verb but the past tense sounds so clumsy.