# With regards to SMS, is the past tense "text" or "texted"?

Tags: word-choice

I've always said "texted" when referring to the past tense of receiving an SMS (text message). However I've noticed a pattern recently that a lot of my friends are saying "text".

> I texted you earlier.

> I text you earlier.

Despite having a red squiggly line under it in Chrome (<sub>[image: look how it squiggles]</sub>), [usage of the word doubled between 2000 and 2008](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=texted&year_start=2000&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctexted%3B%2Cc0). Which word is correct?

Comment: Some people (and I've met them) have taken to using the verb 'to tex'. If you allow that then of course the past participle 'texed' (not 'text') makes perfect sense, e.g. "I will tex you tomorrow" and "I texed her yesterday."

Comment: P.S. I've added an answer to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/how-to-use-text-as-a-verb - In it I've given  an example from a book where 'texed' is used.

Answer (score 0):

The past tense is **texted**. See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/how-to-use-text-as-a-verb) (I don't have enough rep to VTC as duplicate).

The discussion thread [here](http://forums.digitalspy.co.uk/showthread.php?t=603234) shows that some people do use **text** as the past tense (which sounds utterly weird to me), but "texted" is recognised as a proper word.