# Can "post" be past tense?

Tags: past-tense

I seem to recall having heard some people use "post" as a past tense form of "post", rather than "posted". However, this sentence structure is remarkably difficult to google for examples of, let alone representation in dictionaries and similar sources.

"I post flyers every day" <-- present

"I post the flyer yesterday" <-- past

Is this use at all common? And how might I figure that out on my own online?

Comment: I've heard Russians talk like this, not native-speakers.

Comment: *Can “post” be past tense?* No.

Comment: Post is sometimes used to mean after, but this is not a verb.

Comment: No, not really. But someone might mistake _post_ as a member of the monosyllabic final _-d/-t_ verb class, which takes no past or past participle suffix: _bet   quit 
beat  rid
bid  set
burst shed
cast shit
cost shut
cut  slit
fit  spit
hit  split
hurt spread
knit thrust
let  put  
 wed_

Comment: @JohnLawler is there some defining trait of that class or it is an arbitrary list? There are plenty of google results for bursted and knitted

Comment: Those are just the ones in the class. They do have a definition -- they're all monosyllabic and they all end in -d or -t. But it's simpler just to list them. Not all monosyllables ending in -d or -t have identical principal parts like these do; it's a closed set because the rule isn't productive any more.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Cascabel and GEdgar: this usage of *post* seems very unlikely, at least for native speakers.

The Oxford English Dictionary records six different verbs *post*. They are all listed as regular verbs, however, with no special notes. I also looked at the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post), [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/post), [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=post), [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/post), [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/post_2), [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/post?q=post_1), and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/post). They all concur.

As to how you could figure this out on your own online: first, except for the OED, all the other dictionaries are freely accessible, and their not recording any usage of the kind you mention is good evidence that it is not part of Standard English. Second, you can try searching the Corpus of Contemporary American English ([COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)) and the British National Corpus ([BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/)) for POST_v (*post* as a verb). There will be many hits, but in a couple of hours you could go through them all. Similarly, you could search on Google Books for such things as 'post a', 'post the', 'post it', etc. I doubt you will find any hits generated by native speakers. It is of course hard to prove a negative, but this will be another good indication that the usage you report is not part of Standard English.

Answer (score 2):

The standard past tense form of *post* is *posted.*

There are some verbs ending in [st] where standard English uses a past tense form ending in [st] (it is possible to analyze this as a simplification of [stt], with [t] as an irregular past tense marker instead of the syllabic [əd] that regularly appears with verbs ending in [t] or [d]). For example, *cast.*

Furthermore, in some accents of English, word-final [t] is commonly dropped after a preceding obstruent consonant, which includes in [st].

This may lead some speakers to use alternative, non-standard past tense forms for some verbs ending in [st].

- One example is *text,* where it seems that some people use the non-standard past tense form *text* rather than the standard *texted* (see [With regards to SMS, is the past tense "text" or "texted"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273126/with-regards-to-sms-is-the-past-tense-text-or-texted))
- It is also possible to find some examples online of *rest* used as a past tense form (do a Google search for "sat down and rest") even though the standard past tense is *rested.*

So it doesn't seem too unlikely to me that you heard someone use *post* as a past tense form. However, it is not usual and not considered standard.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Cascabel , "post" is not correctly used as a past tense.

There is the possibility that "post" is used as a subjunctive; and that may refer to something in the past.  "The judge ordered that the mayor post the notice in the town square".

Comment: "I post flyers every day" refers to my actions in the past, present and future but I have never heard the construction "I post ..." to refer to the past only.

Answer (score 1):

The past and past participle of "post": posted

"I post flyers every day" <-- this "post" is present tense and

"every day" implies "habitual actions that are repeated often in your life"

so it means a kind of a habit -- posting flyers -- which you had done in the past, are doing now, and will probably be doing if everything is as usual as the past and as now.

"I post the flyer yesterday" <-- "yesterday" means one day ago, which is "past"

So the verb is not correct and needs to be "posted" or "had posted"