# What verb should I use for an SMS or Whatsapp message?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

So when I say that I sent you an SMS or a Whatsapp message, I say that "I texted you", what should I ideally use?

Comment: Like you I say *texted*, but I hope we never arrive at a situation where there is a right and a wrong way to describe these things.

Comment: yeah totally, its just that I've been using "texted" you for a while now. Just wanted to validate.

Comment: Can't fight progress ... WhatsApp could be becoming a verb :-) http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whatsapped

Comment: @k1eran: true that, but my question is if I am sending a text message in form of an SMS, a Whatsapp message or even a tinder message, what should be the best way to say it. "texted you" is the one I have been using for years.

Comment: I would only use “*text*” when it was an actual SMS text message. I would use “IM” more generally for any messaging system that sends instantly/immediately.  I don’t use Watsapp but my daughter uses “Snapchatted” for that particular app.

Comment: Whatever your peers use.  The concepts are so new that there is no established "rule".

Comment: Related question, [How to use “text” as a verb](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30166/how-to-use-text-as-a-verb).

Comment: @randal'thor Why do you think this question should be reopened?

Comment: Any noun can become a verb by popular usage. We now use "google" as a verb, so why not use any company name similarly? I already use *"I have whatsapped you the details"* to make sure the recipient checks their "WhatsApp" inbox and not any other. People will understand it, unless they live under a rock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both terms are "ideally" correct:

***[To message](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/message):***

> - to ​send someone a ​short message using a ​mobile ​phone or ​computer:
>     *I messaged him ​yesterday but haven't had a ​reply.*

***[To text](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/text):***

> - To send someone a text message by ​phone:
>     *I texted her to ​arrange a ​time to ​meet.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: IMHO, thats still a little ambiguous. Did you mean that 'messaged' implies a message in form of text/audio/video and 'texted' means a text message only?

Comment: @Amit - I think that with current widespread technologies 'message' is now often used to mean 'send a message via mobile phone or computer'.  If a friend of yours tells you "I'll send you a message later" what would you understand?

Answer (score 3):

Although the dictionaries have not yet caught up with the distinction, **to text** frequently implies an SMS message transmitted between cellular telephones.

The verb **to message**, meanwhile, has a larger scope. It *may* denote a cell phone SMS message, but may also describe a textual communication on a wide variety of other instant messaging platforms.